# LED light 1st time turn blue only

Tags: electrical

Anyone can help me with this unique situation
Please

Led light wired in porch operating by photocell 
When it turn dark it automatically turn on 
But here is the problem this led light has blue outer ring 
Which turn on every evening first than I have turn off and turned back on 2nd time than inner white light turn than I have to turn it off n on again 3rd time so both blue ring and white light turn on at same time now 
How can I solve this problem and turn both blue ring and white light every time in every evening by photocell 
Some has any idea??
Any help will be highly appreciated 
Victor

Comment: You will need to post what Led light you have that has the blue and white ring.  Manufacturer and Model would be helpful.

Comment: just use a different bulb

Answer (score 0):

You left next to no information as to what LED lighting fixture that you are using so it is hard to provide a specific solution. But with that said there are some types of LED fixtures (sometimes even handheld torch type things) will have a 3 or 4 state On/Off control. This may cycle from OFF-DIM-BRIGHT-OFF with repeated activation of the switch. In your case this cycle seems to be supporting a cycle of OFF-BLUE-WHITE-BOTH-OFF.

For many lights this type of cycle is controlled by a specialized electronics chip with the switch being an input to such switch. If this is the case there is next to no easy solution to make it operate as OFF-BOTH-OFF.

On the other hand if the light has some type of integrated switch these may be a rotating type wafer switch. If so these will have separate wires that go to the BLUE and WHITE sections of the light. The rotation of the switch wafer connects the two wires in the sequence needed to create the lighting cycle. If your light has this type of switching arrangement is would be possible to re-wire it to achieve what you want. A replacement switch may be required.

Answer (score 0):

Some types of photocells are incompatible with some types of LED bulbs as well. LED bulbs run on DC, so there is an AC to DC power supply built into them called a "driver" (which is one reason they are expensive). The way an LED driver draws current from the AC line causes electrical interference on the line, and that can make other electronic devices, such as some types of photocells and dimmers, go haywire. I have had this exact problem with a new fixture that had a built-in photocell, but I tried different brands of LED lamps in it and eventually found one that didn't cause the issue. It's hit and miss, because not all LED drivers are created equal.